# Converting datum reference to EPSG code

Tags: java, geotools

I am using geotools api v17.1.Is there any way to generate epsg code with datum reference and Map projection values ?

**INPUT:**

DATUM OF REF : GDA 94

PROJECTION   : UTM 55S

**Output:**

Expect EPSG code :28355

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by time zone values?

Comment: I have updated the question. I am having datum reference and map projection as my input. Using these 2 values , i have to find the EPSG code